# EF 4 insert entity in relationship with existing entity 

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

```
using (EntitiesContainer db = new EntitiesContainer())
{
    Language language = db.Languages.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Culture == _session.Language);
    Language language2 = new Language { Id = action.Language.Id };
    Operation operation = new Operation { Id = action.Operation.Id };
    //Operation operation = db.Operations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == action.Operation.Id);

    if (!language.Id.Equals(language2.Id))
    {
        db.Languages.Attach(language2);
        action.Language = language2;
    }
    else
    {
        action.Language = language;
    }

    db.Operations.Attach(operation);

    //db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(operation, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);

    action.Operation = operation;
    //operation.Internals.Add(action);

    action.CurrentDetail.Language = language;
    action.CurrentDetail.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    action.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Hello I Try all this scenario in commentary, for link my existing operation to the internal action that inherited from action .. but in any of this scenario, he throw me an error like he want to insert a new operation in the DB (dbo.Operations can accept "Action" NULL value) but the Entity already exist.. Can someone please, give me the golden rule .. to insert entity with relation .. existing or not in EF. It's driving me crazy!

Cordialy,
Julien.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly (your trying to update a relationship), you can use the **stub technique**:

```
Language lang = new Language { Id = action.language_id }; // create stub with ID
db.Languages.Attach(lang); // attach stub to graph
action.language = lang; // update relationship
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi RPM1984, I Will try this.. you understand correctly but i want to insert an entity with a currectly existing relationship not to update a currently existing entity

Comment: @Julien - no problems. The "stub" is an existing relationship. You just need to create a stub for this based on the ID (which you should know), attach it to the graph, then update the relationship. Let me know how you go. The code in your example is quite complicated - so it's hard to figure out which entity needs to be updated. Maybe if you screencapped the relevant part of your EDMX it would be more clear.

Comment: I Update my question if you want to have more detail .. thank you a lot!

Comment: Right, now what is the exact error message you are currently getting with the above code?

Comment: Impossible to Insert NULL value in column "Action" (That is the first column of my table.. is logic..) in the table "Community.dbo.Operation". This column doesn't accept NULL value. Error in INSERT .. But like I said the operation i put in my action, already exist .. why he try to insert them instead of linking them with my new action that I want to INSERT.. thank you a lot .. you save me if you found it ..

Comment: All attach work fine he throw an exception in the SaveChanges() method

Comment: Okay - but in your EDMX (screenshot), you have a field called "Action" on the "Operation" entity - but no navigational property. You should have a navigational property called "Action", which in the database should be a FK on the Operation table. I think that's your problem. Your trying to attach an existing "Action", but it's not exposed as a navigation on your Operation. Know what i mean? See how on ActionDetail you have a nav called "Action", but not on Operation - why?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that it's the problem because Operation have an Navigation properties of Internal that inherited of Action .. but you raise me a doubt in the fact that I have a property that have the same name than an entity .. (the entity Action and the property Operation.Action) I wonder if it can be a conflict? .. And I dont want to attach an existing Action but an existing Operation .. to a new Internal Action.. Thank you for your time .. Julien.

Comment: A an for a response, ActionDetail have an Navigation of Action because is the detail of the base class Action .. ex: Name and description .. for the internationalization purpose ...

Comment: Yes, that is why im confused - if you have "Internals" navigational property which is a subset of "Action", then what is the "Action" property on the entity for? Try removing that...or going back to basics first (create new project with couple of entities, attempt to do what your trying to do). This model is really too complicated for me to help any further. Sorry.

Comment: The Action Property Is for the MVC routeValue .. "Area/Controller/Action" represent an operation .. and a Action represent an Option in a Menu (In my domain).. but I Understand that not in the context its can be very complicated!! Thank you a lot for your patience! I will try to resolve it by my self later!